# Heroku 500 internal error with symfony form

Tags: symfony, heroku

it's my first post here, and firstly sorry for my English, i hope you understand me !!!
i build a Symfony app deployed on Heroku, in my app i have some forms.
At begin that working, but since last deploy i have a 500 internal error.
the cli logs says

```
2021-02-24T17:52:54.419179+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24T17:52:54.414656+00:00] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Could not load type "App\Form
\CreateBilletType": class does not exist." at /app/vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php line 85 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Form\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Could not load typ
e \"App\\Form\\CreateBilletType\": class does not exist. at /app/vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php:85)"} []
2021-02-24T17:52:54.425098+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.10.185.7 - - [24/Feb/2021:17:52:54 +0000] "GET /create HTTP/1.1" 500 831 "http://jmpmapi.herokuapp.com/admin" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebK
it/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36
2021-02-24T17:52:54.425339+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24T17:52:54.423782+00:00] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
2021-02-24T17:52:54.425534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/create" host=jmpmapi.herokuapp.com request_id=bde83eee-793c-4d86-ae7c-68bdbf10cba4 fwd="78.223.111.34" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5
6ms status=500 bytes=1223 protocol=http
```

here my code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Billet;
use App\Form\CreateBilletType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class CreateController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/create", name="admin_create")
     * @param FormFactoryInterface $factory
     * @param Request $request
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     * @return Response
     */
    public function Create(FormFactoryInterface $factory, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {
        $builder = $factory->createBuilder(CreateBilletType::class);

        $form = $builder->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $billet = new Billet();
            $billet->setTitle($data->getTitle())
                ->setContent($data->getContent())
                ->setDate($data->getDate())
                ->setAuthors($data->getAuthors())
                ->setPicture($data->getPicture());
            #DD($billet);
            $em->persist($billet);
        }
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('create/index.html.twig', [
            'formView' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

It's a CRUD and i have the same problame for Update !
Could you help me, i'm a 46 years old Junior, and after a lot of searching, i'm deseperate  .

Thanks,
Bruno

Comment: Can you please confirm that your form is at the same place `App\Form\CreateBilletType`?

Comment: Very thanks, already because you understand me, so i'm happy for that and yes i confirm that is the same place ,the day before yesterday it had working but not right now, i don't understand what is happen with heroku, at home everything works

Comment: Caution, your flush is outside the `$form->isSubmitted()` . I don't think it's what is making the 500 error but you should fix this little thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an other way, without `FormFactoryInterface`:

```php
public function create(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
    $router = $this->get('router'); // Or inject RouterInterface
    $billet = new Billet();
    $options = [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'action' => $router->generate('admin_create'),
    ];
    $form = $this->createForm(CreateBilletType::class, $billet, $options);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $billet = $form->getData();
            $em->persist($billet);
            $em->flush();
        } 
    }

    $result['form'] = $form->createView();
    $response = $this->render('create/index.html.twig', $result);
    $response->setSharedMaxAge($someTtl);
    $response->setPublic();

    return $response;
}
```

But like that, your form need to be connected with your entity. In your formType you need this:

```php
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection' => false, // or true like you want
            'validation_groups' => null,
            'data_class' => Billet::class
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: i had to do a dashboard with a CRUD, but i didn't know the make:crud method in symfony, now is done, but as i have a foreign key, of course i have get throw an beautiful error, so after a lot of searching, i has finally find the __toString method.
and now that work at home, i juste hope will be the same thing on Heroku. However thank you very much for your help because i have learn a lot with your responses so thank you again ___ and i write in english !!! It's so COOL

Comment: I'm happy that it was helpfull for you :). Can you mark my answer as "accepted" please ?

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't know that i do it, it's done